# run php output as shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I want to use shell and php together.
First I tried:
shell_exec vs functions is disabled and must be so.
But php does not give me permission to run shell_exec()
So, I gave up and tried to make a .sh, call php,store output of php as sh file and run sh file.
Here is sh code

```
#!/bin/bash/
php test.php -> running php file/ test.php saves commands in script.sh
sh script.sh -> running the commands
rm script.sh -> removing the commands
```

But there must be a better way from this file process.
Can I run output of test.php directly in .sh file?
Can I run shell_exec ?

Note: I have root access of the server.

Comment: If you have root access to the server, surely you can just enable `shell_exec()` in php.ini, right?

Comment: This is shared server I cannot enable shell_exec for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe (`|`) the output of PHP to `sh` to be executed:

```
$ php -r 'echo "echo \$PATH";' | sh
```

outputs:

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I've read some statements using `-r` for simplicity, but you can read from a file by passing a script to php:

```
$ php test.php | sh
```